# How to create a Google Form with randomly selected images?

Tags: javascript, google-forms

I want to create a google form where a user sees a randomly image selected from a database I've collected and select options based on it so that we can generate captions for the images. How do I set up the Google Form so that it displays a different image every time someone fills it up and so that it stores the options selected along with the image name?

I've uploaded the image database to my drive folder but I have no idea how to select a random one for my form.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the google forms api running, you can do something like the following. Note: you'll also need to get the google drive api running, too.

```
// create an array of images from a google drive folder
// you'll need the id of the folder
var imageFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(imageFolderId);
var imageFiles = imageFolder.getFiles();
var imageArray = [];
while (imageFiles.hasNext()) {
  var image = imageFiles.next();
  imageArray.push(image);
}
```

```
// when creating your form, use the imageArray created in the previous step
// you'll index the imageArray with a random number from 0 to the number of images - 1
var randomImageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length);
var img = imageArray[randomImageIndex]
form.addImageItem()
    .setTitle('My Random Image title')
    .setHelpText('My Random Image text') // The help text is the image description
    .setImage(img);
```